# Spring Boot app passing JVM args automatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using Eclipse STS4. Spring Boot 2.4.0 app, this one happens to be Webflux / Netty. Is there a way to specify JVM args in a way that hits in various run scenarios?

1. debugging / running through STS4
2. running through mvn command line
3. running through standalone

I know I can pass in cmd args to all these different ways, but kind of looking for something I can put in my application.properties or something like that? Just trying to avoid having to document it, educate people on how to run it properly, etc.

I've tried various things I found through Google like inlineConfScript, etc. but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `JAVA_OPTS` in your `.conf`? See Customizing the [start script](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file)

Comment: I tried the conf file, but it doesn't seem to get picked up when running in Eclipse. If I put my cmd line args in the run configuration, then it does, but trying to avoid that since it would need to be done on every machine.